# An array of Threads in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm looking to build an application useing mutipul threads in Java (Android) something like this (n.b. this is off the top of my head and most likely riddled with errors)

```
thread [] jobs
int threadCounter

    // Some code

job = new Runnabul(){
    // Do something intresting
}

    // Some more code

while(true){
 jobs[threadCounter] = new job();
 threadCounter++;
}
```

This will at some point cause the phone to run out of memory and die, so to my questron, how do I know when I'm close to running out of resorces (and so I can slow the creation of new threads)?

Thanks

Comment: You should use a thread pool as offered by java.util.concurrent. No point in having more threads than the device can handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use the executor service, as described [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html). Create a pool of thread, and then just pass a Runnable (a task to execute).

As derekerdmann say, if you really want to do an array of thread, use ASyncTask. The system will take care to stop them in case of low memory, and you can manage them more easily than thread.

Comment: It was a hard chooise as to who get's the magic green tick, I think AsyncTask is what I need (I thorght it could only be ran once so I dismissed it initaly). But I'll give it to you Nitro as you gave me the heads up on the executor service as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using Android's [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead of your own threads.  They use Java's executors from java.util.concurrent, so the OS manages thread creation and system resources completely on its own.

AsyncTasks also have useful methods for publishing progress and updating the GUI on the UI thread.